# KnpMenuBundle children Object make something else current

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I have the following structure:

```
/list
which shows the list of objects
```

and also

```
/list/{id}
Which shows one Object in detail
```

I now want the Navigation to make the `/list` as the active element if one of the detail pages are selected and of course if the real list is selected.

My Navigation looks like this:

```
Home
List
Misc
[...]
```

I was reading through some other questions but I wasn't able to find the right answer for me. Since I don't have a Menu Item which describes `List Detail`